# ActiveMQ: Can i make Queue as a subscriber to Topic?

Tags: activemq-classic

I would like to make ActiveMQ Queue as a subscriber for an existing ActiveMQ Topic. I am not sure how to do this in ActiveMQ. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not subscribe but you can use camel routes or destination interceptors to forward messages from topic to queue